# Stuck on Structs(c++)

Tags: c++, function, struct

Okay so this is what Ive been asked to do "make a struct called Coordinate that contains the
latitude and longitude of a point on the surface of the Earth. The struct should also store a
label or name for the coordinate (e.g., “Calgary”). Both the latitude and longitude member
variables should be of type double and should be stored in units of radians.
Once the struct is defined, write a function to read the label/name as well as the latitude and
longitude of a single coordinate and store them in a Coordinate struct that is then returned to
the calling function. The function should prompt for the angles in units of degrees and then
convert the values into radians (as per the above)."

This is what I have written

```
struct coordinate
{
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    string city;
};

void Readcoordinate();
int main()
{
    coordinate startPt, endPt;


}

void Readcoordinate()
{
    cout << "Enter Longitude(in degrees)" << endl;
    cin >> startPt.latitude
        >> startPt.longitude
        >> startPt.city;
}
```

and i keep on getting a error. any help?
thanks

Comment: Did you *read* the error message?

Comment: yes it says Error 1 error C2065: 'startPt' : undeclared identifier

Comment: `startPt` is defined in main but not in `Readcoordinate`. Either pass it with a pointer or return the value.

Comment: Your function `readcoordinate` isn't a method of struct coordinate, therefore it doesn't recognize its attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared `coordinate startPt, endPt;` in `main()` and you are trying to access them `Readcoordinate(). To resolve error you should declare`coordinate startPt, endPt;`in`Readcoordinate()` or pass them as argument.

```
coordinate Readcoordinate()
{
    coordinate startPt;
    cout << "Enter Longitude(in degrees)" << endl;
    cin >> startPt.latitude
        >> startPt.longitude
        >> startPt.city;
   return startPt;
}
```

or

```
int main()
{
      coordinate startPt, endPt;
      Readcoordinate(startPt);
      Readcoordinate(endPt);
}
void Readcoordinate(coordinate &Pt)
{
   cout << "Enter Longitude(in degrees)" << endl;
    cin >> Pt.latitude
        >> Pt.longitude
        >> Pt.city;
}
```

Comment: thanks but with the 2nd option I get error Error 1 error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are defined in `main`, so their scope is limited to `main` only.
You need to define them in the function where you are using them, or you may define those variables as global, so that they are accessible in both `main` and your function. You may also need to call the function in the main.

**Local variables:**

```
void Readcoordinate();
int main()
{
    Readcoordinate();
}

void Readcoordinate()
{
    coordinate startPt, endPt;    // Locally defined
    cout << "Enter Longitude(in degrees)" << endl;
    cin >> startPt.latitude
    >> startPt.longitude
    >> startPt.city;
}
```

**Global variables:**

```
coordinate startPt, endPt;    // Globally defined
void Readcoordinate();
int main()
{
    Readcoordinate();
}

void Readcoordinate()
{
    cout << "Enter Longitude(in degrees)" << endl;
    cin >> startPt.latitude
    >> startPt.longitude
    >> startPt.city;
}
```